# How can I bake an action to an object without the object moving out of place?

Tags: animation

So, I have a set of objects that I am trying to bake an action to, but when I do that, the objects fly out elsewhere outside of where I want them. Is there a way to make it so the animation is baked exactly where I want it? I have a baked animation which works fine, but then I parented it to an empty and then copied everything so I could move it over while retaining proper animations. When I bake action, it flies off. How can I fix this?